# Creating a “method” method on an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

Can someone explain me how they are creating a "method" method on an object.

```
var foo = {};

foo.method = function(name, cb){
  this[name] = cb;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're assigning the key `method` to a function - that's a method. If you're wondering how the key `method` is used, it's because it's not a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

The actual method creates a new method with the provided `name`, and sets it to the `cb`. (This can also be used to make properties, not just methods).

```js
var foo = {};

foo.method = function(name, cb) {
  this[name] = cb;
};

foo.method("sayHello", () => console.log("Hello!"));
foo.sayHello();
```